# Find percentage between two matching column values in a different row

Tags: google-sheets

I need to find the percentage between finished / unfinished. However I can't just divide across a single row, as the countries need to match. Is there a specific formula that can help do this?

Below is an example of the data:

| COUNTRY | UNFINISHED | COUNTRY | FINISHED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 500 | CA | 150 |
| UK | 300 | US | 200 |
| CA | 300 | UK | 170 |

Is there a way to calculate finished / unfinished, but still have US / US and UK / UK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two vlookups:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2,C:D,2,false)/vlookup(F2,A:B,2,false)
```

[image]